# Borel set in the Cantor set.

Tags: descriptive-set-theory

I'm working with [this article](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm150/fm15016.pdf) of Stevo Todorcevic and I am stuck with the fact that not all orthogonal definable families can be separated. More concretely, I am unable to prove that the sets $A=\{a_i\}$ and $B$ are Borel sets (taking the topology of the Cantor set). I've managed to notice that $$A=\bigcup_{n,m=1}^{\infty} {\{2^n(2m+1)}\}$$ and I was trying to prove that these singletons are open sets. However, I think there's something that I'm missing or simply I've gone the wrong way.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: I think that you might have misunderstood the definitions of $a_i$'s.

Comment: @AsafKaragila yeah, that is something I'm considering, but I do not really see what could be an alternative definition.

Comment: No singleton is open in the Cantor set.

Comment: I find the closure of this question altogether incomprehensible. In particular, I fail to see what more the OP could reasonably be expected to say.

Answer (score 1):

Each set $a_i$ is simply a point in the Cantor set $C$, so $A$ is countable and therefore Borel. Suppose that $b\in C$ and $b\perp a_i$ for each $i$. Each $n\in b$ can be written uniquely as $2^{k(n)}m(n)$, where $m(n)$ is odd. For each $i$ let $b_i=\{n\in b:k(n)=i\}$; then each $b_i$ is finite. Indeed, $B$ is the set of all $b\in C$ such that $b_i$ is finite for each $i$. For a fixed $i$, the set of $b\in C$ such that $b_i$ is finite is $F_\sigma$, so $B$ is $F_{\sigma\delta}$.

Comment: Why is "the set of $b \in C$ such that $b_i$ is finite" $F_{\sigma}$?

Comment: @Whoknows: $\{b\in C:n\notin b\}$ is closed for each $n$, and the intersection of closed sets is closed, so $\{b\in C:b\cap a=\varnothing\}$ is closed for any fixed $a\subseteq\Bbb Z^+$. For a fixed $i$, the set of $b\in C$ such that $b_i$ is finite is the union of countably many such sets, one for each cofinite subset $a$ of the set of $n$ such that $k(n)=I$.